# How can I get username with userid in generic list wpf C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox, generic-list

I programing an WPF client application. I have a rest api, the WPF client is communicating with this. I made a combobox in wpf, the data binding is ok.

**XAML markup:**

```
<ComboBox Name="usernameBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
          Margin="127,33,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="152" Height="24" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding UserList}" DisplayMemberPath="Username"/>
```

This is working fine. But I have one generic list `Userlist`, I am binding this for the combobox. I want that for the username is the combobox I can get a variable with userid.

Model\Users class:

```
namespace Desktop.Model
{
    public class Users
    {
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public string Fullname { get; set; }
        public int Authority { get; set; }
    }
}
```

ViewModel/UserViewModel class:

```
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight;
using Desktop.Model;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Net.Http.Formatting;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace Desktop.ViewModel
{
    public class UserViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        public List<Users> UserList { get; set; }

        public UserViewModel()
        {
            UserList = new List<Users>();
            string url = "http://localhost:1234/api/users";
            var json = new WebClient().DownloadString(url);
            UserList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Users>>(json);
        }
    }
}
```

Get api/users json:

```
[
  {
    "UserID": 1,
    "Username": "admin",
    "Password": "password",
    "Fullname": "teszt",
    "Authority": 1
  }
]
```

Sorry for my bad English. Please help me! Thank you.

Comment: Use SelectedItem binding and in selected item you will have whole user object. Is this you want to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve.

XAML markup:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="usernameBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="127,33,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="152" ItemsSource="{Binding UserList}" SelectedValuePath="UserId" DisplayMemberPath="Username"/>
```

Codebehind:

```
var id = usernameBox.SelectedValue;
```

It's working fine!

Answer (score 0):

Using MVVM like you are you can add to your XAML:

```
SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedUser}"
```

in your ViewModel:

```
private Users _user;
public Users SelectedUser
{
    get
    {
        return _user;
    }
    set
    {
        if (_user == value)
            return;
        _user = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedUser));
    }
}
```

Done, use the property `SelectedUser` to get your selected "`Users`" in your ComboBox